# How to get STDERR in Perl from a command executed in pipe with su -c

Tags: perl, error-handling, sudo, su

I'm trying to capture the output of the command executed as a different user using:

```
my $command = qq(sudo su - <username> -c '/usr/bin/whatever');
my $pid = open $cmdOutput, "-|", $command;
```

How can I capture the STDERR of `/usr/bin/whatever`?

I tried

```
$pid = open $cmdOutput, "-|", $command || die " something went wrong: $!";
```

but it looks like this is capturing the possible errors of "open" itself.

I also tried

```
my $command = qq(sudo su - <username> -c '/usr/bin/whatever' 2>/tmp/error.message);
```

which will redirect the STDERR to the file, which I can parse later, but I wanted some more straightforward solution.

Also, I only want to use core modules.

Comment: Why do you say *"Also I don't want to use external modules"* and what do you mean by "external"?

Comment: @Borodin well, I'm not allowed to install any CPAN modules, or modules which are not part of Perl distribution. I have corrected my question :)

Comment: If you "don't want to" use CPAN modules, then you're using the wrong language. If you're "not allowed to" use CPAN modules, then you're in the wrong job :-)

Comment: Also, if you only want to use modules that are included in the Perl distribution, then you'll need to tell us which version of Perl you are using. The list of bundled modules changes with every release.

Comment: :) I'm using  perl, v5.8.4 built for i86pc-solaris-64int and don't laugh please, I'm not admin of that platform, pure user only. Thats why I'm not allowed to install anything in perl

Comment: Are you using an operating system from 2004 as well? Is it still supported? Do you get security patches for it?

Comment: I just noticed the (added) restriction to core modules. Are you sending input to your command?

Comment: @zdim, nope, not sending input to the command only executing that command (sometimes with arguments) and catching the output. Out of curiosity are you thinking of backticking instead of open() ?

Comment: You don't need root access to install a Perl module for your own private use

Comment: @dave, nope OS is from 2011 and as I wrote, I'm not sysadmin of that system, so can't help it much :)

Comment: @borodin I know that ;) but installing modules for private use is not very future proof I believe. Trust me I would do that as I'm tired of all restrictions I 'm facing but....

Comment: @taiko: I'm not sure what you mean by "future proof". If you install a  module under your own source directory then you can just distribute it as part of the release

Comment: @borodin :) well you're technically right. But admin's explicitely mentioned no no-core modules should be used. However, If no other option, I will need to do that, and try to hide it :) Until then trying to find out other options ;)

Comment: @taiko: That's especially true of pure Perl modules, which you could just copy into place and say you wrote it yourself!

Comment: @taiko I've considerably reworked the addition to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered thoroughly [in perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3F). Since you are using a *piped open*, the relevant examples are those that go by `open3` from the core [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html) module.

Another option is to use [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.94/lib/IPC/Run.pm) for managing your processes, and the `pump` function will do what you need. The `IPC::Open3` documentation says for `IPC::Run`

> This is a CPAN module that has better error handling and more facilities than Open3.

With either of these you can manipulate `STDOUT` and `STDERR` separately or together, as needed.  For convenient and complete output capture also see [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Capture-Tiny-0.42/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm).

Other than `2>output` redirection, there are no more elementary methods for the piped open.

---

If you don't mind mixing the streams or losing `STDOUT` altogether, another option is

```
my $command = 'cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null'          # Remove 1>/dev/null to have both
my $pid = open my $cmdOutput, "-|", $command;

while (<$cmdOutput>) { print }                # STDERR only
```

The first redirection merges `STDERR` stream with `STDOUT` so you get them both, and mixed (with `STDOUT` subject to buffering, thus things may well come out of order). The second redirect sends the `STDOUT` away so with it in place you read only the command's `STDERR` from the handle.

---

The question is about running an external command using `open` but I'd like to mention that the canonical and simple [qx](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) (*backticks*) can be used in the same way. It returns the `STDOUT` so redirection just like above is needed to get `STDERR`. For completeness:

```
my $cmd = 'cmd_to_execute';
my $allout = qx($cmd 2>&1);              # Both STDOUT and STDERR in $out, or
my $stderr = qx($cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null);  # Only STDERR
my $exit_status = $?;
```

The `qx` puts the child process exit code (status) in `$?`. This can then be inspected for failure modes; see a summary in the `qx` page or a very thorough discussion in *[I/O operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators)*.

Note that the `STDERR` returned this way is *from the command*, if it ran. If the command itself couldn't be run (for a typo in command name, or `fork` failed for some reason) then `$?` will be `-1` and the error will be in `$!`.

Comment: @taiko Thank you for the attribution.  I don't know whether you still have interest in this, but just to let you know that I added a summary of `qx` use for this.

Comment: saw it. So far I used IPC::Open3 as you suggested and its doing its job for me. But I like qx also. Never used qx before and I will try it. Thank you very much for the summary.

Comment: @taiko  Great -- open3 is a powerful tool.  While `qx` (backticks) is dirt simple and yet quite adequate :)  Thanks for responding!

Comment: yeah it looks very good indeed. I'm using it as descibed in http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=151886, but I understood its not good to mix buffered I/O (like read() or <FH>) with select() as one of monks suggested. Anyhow I couldn't find another way yet. Somebody suggested sysread, but I need to read whole line ended with \n\r and not just number of bytes. However I have to admint, that I don't undrestand whole thing about sysread, buffering, IO etc yet

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [zdim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653379/zdim) I used the IPC::Open3 module for the matter and I've got something like this doing the job for me

```
 $instanceCommand = qq(sudo su - <username> -c '<command>');
 my ($infh,$outfh,$errfh,$pid);
 $errfh = gensym();
 $pid = open3($infh, $outfh, $errfh, $instanceCommand);
 my $sel = new IO::Select;
 $sel->add($outfh,$errfh);
 while (my @ready = $sel->can_read){
      foreach my $fh (@ready){
           my $line =<$fh>;
           if (not defined $line){
                $sel->remove($fh);
                next;
                }
           if ($fh == $outfh){
                chomp($line);
                #<----- command output processing ----->
                }
           elsif ($fh == $errfh){                                                                                      
                chomp $line;
                #<----- command error processing ----->
                }
           else {
                die "Reading from something else\n";
                }
            }
      }
waitpid($pid, 0);
```

Maybe not completely bullet proof, but its working fine for me. Even whilst executing funny cascaded script as < command > .

Comment: Just saw this accidentally, when answering a related question.  Nice to post your full solution :)

Comment: @zdim yeah. It might help somebody :)

Comment: Right, it well may. It is interesting and non-trivial, too.  A comment: for comparing strings there is `eq` operator, `==` is for numbers. A filehandle is a "wrapped" number (file descriptor) so I'd use `eq` for them. (Also, the `Scalar::Util::looks_like_number` says that a filehandle doesn't look like a number.)  I know that `IO::Select` docs use `==` in their example, and `IPC::Open3` mentions integers but these _are_ lexical filehandles. (I don't know of any reason to use `==` for filehandles.)

Comment: will try to change it in my script to see if it makes any difference

Comment: @zdim tried to use string operators, instead of number operators, but it looks there is no difference, at least not in my implermentation. Funny enough

Comment: I recalled a possibiilty, that when `==` operator has filehandles to compare it may actually retrieve the file descriptor and compare that.  If that's the case then `==` _is_ better to use.  But I am not at all sure about this.  Yes, it's interesting how things go under the hood (when I get to see/learn about it!)

Answer (score 0):

The desired destination, opened for writing, could be dup()'ed to FD #2