# How to open files through fork in perl? Perl migration issue (5.6 to 5.8)

Tags: perl, fork

We are doing perl upgrade (5.6 to 5.8) for one of our application.

In 5.6 we are using the below sample code to implement multi threading,

```
$connection->{output} = new IO::File;
my $pid = open ($connection->{output}, "-|");
        if (not defined $pid) {
                die qq("open fork failed: $!);
            } elsif ($pid != 0) {
               $connection->{pid} = $pid;
                next LOOP;
            } else {
               select(STDOUT);
               $| = 1;
               print "Something";
               POSIX::_exit(0);
}
```

But in perl 5.8, '-|' is not supported. So I am trying to do the same through fork(). But How to implement '-|' through fork and to make the code work just as in 5.6.

Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: You'd need to set up a pipe to get an equivalent of  `-|` with fork.  Can you not use piped `open` with `-|` instead? It forks, sets `STDOUT` for the new process, and is non-blocking.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, could you please elaborate..

Comment: I don't know what `IO::File` does but `-|` usually means to pipe output of a process.  If you use `fork` to create a new process you'd have to use `pipe` so that the processes can communicate.  Otherwise, `my $pid = open my $fh, '-|', $cmd` does that altogether.  Then you read from `$fh` and that's the `STDOUT` of `$cmd`. Is that what you need to do?

Comment: The page for `open` has examples.  Search for "from\_kid". Also, [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218998/perl-how-to-get-stderr-from-command-executed-in-pipe-with-su-c/) comes to mind readily.  There is far more out there on "_piped open_".  (If I understood what you need to do.)

Comment: Perl 5.8 is still REALLY OLD. If you're doing an update, why not just push forward to a version that isn't end of life? Moving from a 2003 version of perl to a 2008 version of perl is a step up, but you're still 8 years behind the curve.

Answer (score 1):

```
defined( my $pid = open ($connection->{output}, "-|") )
   or die($!);

if ($pid) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

is similar to

```
pipe(my ($FROM_CHILD, $TO_PARENT))
   or die($!);

defined( my $pid = fork() )
   or die($!);

if ($pid) {
   close($TO_PARENT);
   ...
} else {
   close($FROM_CHILD);
   open(STDOUT, '<&', $TO_PARENT)
      or die($!);

   ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to do the same (pipe and fork). But control is moving to either Parent or Child. Both blocks are not getting executed. Every time control goes to only else block.

Comment: That's an entirely separate issue